# Nginx reverse proxy on python simplehttpserver

Tags: python, nginx, reverse-proxy, simplehttpserver

I was trying to setup NGINX reverse proxy on Python SimpleHTTPServer. My `web.conf` file present in **`/etc/nginx/conf.d`** and the setting present in the file is as follows.

```
server {
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.3:8000/;
    } 
}
```

My NGINX is up and running. I did the reload after saving the `web.conf` file. On the other hand, I'm also running Python SimpleHTTPServer in directory **`home/user/projects/`**

But when I open the browser and visit `localhost` it shows me the NGINX Welcome Page and not the `index.html` file which is inside the directory in which I'm running Python SimpleHTTPServer.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1- you forgot in your configuration file to specify the listening port
   just add :

```
listen 80;
```

2- the default configuration is still active check if there is symlink called default in:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

and delete it
3- Preferably add your settings file in

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/
```

then make a symlink to it in sites-enabled  , that way you can just delete the symlink if you want to deactivate the site instead of removing the configuration . instead of putting it in conf.d.

check [how to configure nginx](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx) for more details